# JSON - Error on putting a JSON string inside a JSON object

Tags: java, json, jersey, gson

I have a web-service in Java with Jersey to create and edit prices of a market. To do that, I send a JSON object containing the market informations, including another JSON object for the prices.

For example, this is the JSON I'm posting through Postman:

```
{
    "name": "Market 01",
    "address": "Market 01 street",
    "prices": "{\"watermelon\": \"5.40\", \"melon\": \"2.55\"}"
}
```

On the web-server side, I try to create a list of the prices using GSON, but I can't get it to work. My objective here is to check on the difference between the new prices and the current prices. Below, there is my POJO Price.java, what I'm trying to do on the Controller for the edit and the Exception I'm geting on Postman:

POJO - Price.java

```
public class Price {
    private String nome;
    private Double preco;
    //Getters and setters also
}
```

MarketController.java

```
Collection<Price> prices = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Price>>(){}.getType());
```

Exception raised on MarketController.java:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

**EDIT:** The solution that worked for me based on @A2H response:

POJO class - Price.java

```
public class Price {
    private String name;
    private Double price;

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"name\":\"" + name + "\", \"price\":" + price + "}";
    }
}
```

POJO class - Market.java

```
public class Market{
    ...
    //Include as a List<Price>
    private List<Price> prices;
    ...
}
```

MarketController.java

```
// When going from List<Price> to JSON String
String prices = gson.toJson(market.getPrices());
// When going from JSON String to List<Price>
List<Price> prices = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Price>>(){}.getType());
```

This code is well rounded for this situation, where you need to transform from List to JSON String and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POJO implies that you should have an array of prices in your `JSON` object.

Here's a full working example.

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TESTTEST {

    public class MarketInfo {
        String name;
        String address;
        List<Price> prices;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public List<Price> getPrices() {
            return prices;
        }

        public void setPrices(List<Price> prices) {
            this.prices = prices;
        }
    }

    public class Price {
        String nome;
        Double preco;

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public Double getPreco() {
            return preco;
        }

        public void setPreco(Double preco) {
            this.preco = preco;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{\"nome\":\"" + nome + "\", \"preco\":" + preco + "}";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = "{\"name\": \"Market 01\",\"address\": \"Market 01 street\","
            + "\"prices\": [{\"nome\":\"watermelon\",\"preco\":\"5.40\"}, {\"nome\":\"melon\",\"preco\": \"2.55\"}]}";
        MarketInfo res = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MarketInfo.class);
        System.out.println(res.getPrices());
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I get this to work with Hibernate? I mean, my objective is to store the prices as a JSON String on the DB.

Comment: Well, this is a different question, but I assume you have a named query to which you can pass on the JSON string and save it in the field of your choice of a table. Then, whenever you read that JSON string you can construct the `object` as described above.

Comment: I did what you answered and now I am able to get the JSON and save it to the DB. The problem is when I try to re-create the List<Price> to compare with the new one. Is it possible to compare without re-creating the List or I really need to do this step?

Comment: Holy shit. I got it to work! Thanks so much, man! Gonna edit the question to include the answer as well!

Comment: OK, I'm glad it worked for you.
If you want to compare the objects, it's better to construct two `Price` objects and see if they are equal or not, instead of comparing the `JSON` strings. Override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `Price` class to include your logic of comparing two instances of the class `Price`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because a `List` would be represented by a JSON array, not by an object as you provide. You can try to deserialize to a map (or, send an array).

Comment: Can you show some example, please? What you're saying is something like this: `Collection<Price> prices =  = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Double>>(){}.getType());`?

Comment: Yes, kind of. This will give you another error because the result is not assignment compatible with `Collection<Price>`.

Comment: Can you change the input string? For example: `{"nome":"melon", "preco":5.40}`

Comment: If yes, then you can have an array of such objects, which can be easily translated to a `List<Price>`.

Comment: @A2H The same error persists when I change the input to your example.